# Left join with generate_series misleads the planner

Tags: postgresql-9.6

Using postgres 9.6, i'm currently managing time-based data with the following structure:

```
     Column     |                 Type                  | Collation | Nullable | Default
----------------+---------------------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 key            | character varying                     |           | not null |
 start_datetime | timestamp with time zone              |           | not null |
 end_datetime   | timestamp with time zone              |           | not null |
 value          | double precision                      |           |          |
Indexes:
    "perf_10t_series_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (key, start_datetime)
```

I wish to load the data from this table in a python Series (from the pandas library). The tricky point is that i need to have null values properly inserted in the Series if there is no row in the database. Reindexing the series with pandas is okay, but isn't particularly fast, so I tried to do this in SQL with the following query:

```
SELECT value FROM (
                SELECT start_datetime, value
                FROM perf_10t_series AS origin
                WHERE origin.key = 'A'
                AND start_datetime >= '2019-01-01 00:00'
                AND end_datetime <= '2020-01-01 00:00'
            ) data
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT * FROM 
            generate_series('2019-01-01 00:00'::timestamptz,
                            '2020-01-01 00:00'::timestamptz - interval '1 second',
                            interval '10 minutes')

                AS d (datetime)
            ) idx ON idx.datetime = data.start_datetime
            ORDER BY idx.datetime
```

Unfortunately, the planner decides to use the following query plan (An Index Scan Loop).

```
Sort  (cost=8626.83..8629.33 rows=1000 width=16) (actual time=640.423..648.448 rows=105264 loops=1)
  Sort Key: d.datetime
  Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 2680kB
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.57..8577.01 rows=1000 width=16) (actual time=19.060..581.976 rows=105264 loops=1)
        ->  Function Scan on generate_series d  (cost=0.01..10.01 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=19.006..32.620 rows=105264 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using perf_10t_series_pkey on perf_10t_series origin  (cost=0.56..8.56 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=105264)
              Index Cond: (((key)::text = 'A'::text) AND (d.datetime = start_datetime) AND (start_datetime >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
              Filter: (end_datetime <= '2021-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)
Planning time: 0.251 ms
Execution time: 655.437 ms
```

Looking at the plan, it seems the problem is that the database misestimates the number of lines returned by generate_series. (by a factor of 50).

This is confirmed by the fact that using a temporary table (which can probably be easier to estimate) leads to a different plan:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_index (
  start_datetime TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
);

INSERT INTO my_index SELECT * FROM
            generate_series('2019-01-01 00:00'::timestamptz,
                            '2020-01-01 00:00'::timestamptz - interval '1 second',
                            interval '10 minutes');

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT value FROM (
                SELECT start_datetime, value
                FROM perf_10t_series AS origin
                WHERE origin.key = 'A'
                AND start_datetime >= '2019-01-01 00:00'
                AND end_datetime <= '2020-01-01 00:00'
            ) data
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
              SELECT *
              FROM my_index
            ) idx ON idx.start_datetime = data.start_datetime
            ORDER BY idx.start_datetime
```

```
  ->  Sort  (cost=225094.20..225220.46 rows=50502 width=16) (actual time=77.267..80.013 rows=52560 loops=1)
        Sort Key: origin.start_datetime
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3830kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on perf_10t_series origin  (cost=11021.10..221148.97 rows=50502 width=16) (actual time=27.229..67.811 rows=52560 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (((key)::text = 'A'::text) AND (start_datetime >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
              Filter: (end_datetime <= '2020-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 263088
              Heap Blocks: exact=4897
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on perf_10t_series_pkey  (cost=0.00..11008.47 rows=299991 width=0) (actual time=26.607..26.607 rows=315648 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (((key)::text = 'A'::text) AND (start_datetime >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
Planning time: 0.176 ms
Execution time: 103.966 ms
```

That's much better.

So my question is: how can I provide to postgres a hint about the number of lines that will be returned by generate_series, or any other strategy that will force postgres to use the "good" plan? I would like to avoid creating the temporary table.

Comment: The planner simply has no knowledge about the amount of data returned from the function call `generate_series()` and uses some hard-coded estimates. I _think_ this changed with Postgres 12, but I am not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can help the planner by using a subquery limiting the output of generate_series. Technically, the LIMIT is useless, since it will returns exactly the number of rows that `generate_series` would have returned!

But the fact, that we limit help the query planner, which push the cost of the query down, which avoid JIT compilation, the main culprit of the slowdown.

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series(in_from,
        in_to - in_interval,
        in_interval) s LIMIT (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (in_to - in_from))/EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM in_interval))
```

Related to [Why is my nested loop taking so much time?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/310235/why-is-my-nested-loop-taking-so-much-time/310242#310242)

You can also use this function in place of the original

```
-- Technically this LIMIT clause is useless. However, without it the query planner
-- is unable to correctly estimate the numbers of row in generate_series
-- which cause JIT compilation, slowing down the query considerably
-- See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/310235/why-is-my-nested-loop-taking-so-much-time/310242#310242
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_series_fixed(in_from TIMESTAMPTZ, in_to TIMESTAMPTZ, in_interval INTERVAL) RETURNS TIMESTAMPTZ AS $$
  SELECT generate_series(in_from, in_to, in_interval)
  LIMIT  (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (in_to - in_from))/EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM in_interval)) + 1; -- I am unsure about the exact formula, but over estimating 1 row is fine...
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```